# Apache reverse proxy - rewrite and Substitute returning answer

Tags: apache

We have reverse proxy server which use rewrite rule to redirect one address to another.

When redirection is working, we get back an answer from that site (google) as a txt page.

Now, we wish to Substitute few words in that page and direct it to the source server that asked for it.

Our configuration looks like this:

```
ProxyRequests Off
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/books\.google\.com(.*) https://books.google.com/$1
Substitute "s/thumbnail_url/test/ni"
```

We do get the page back from google, but Substitute of words in the page is not working.

Hoping someone can answer it.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Found the way to do so, by adding the following lines:

SSLProxyEngine On
RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"

Substitute "s/thumbnail_url/test/ni" [P]

Cause [P] will made the all query to work with https (as rewrite rule defined) and two first lines support SSL on apache proxy.

Lavi